# a function to return the quiz nid

Tags: 7, quiz

There is a template file in the quiz/template/quiz-report-form.tpl.php of Quiz module.
this is the code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Themes the question report
 *
 * Available variables:
 * $form - FAPI array
 *
 * All questions are in form[x] where x is an integer.
 * Useful values:
 * $form[x]['question'] - the question as a FAPI array(usually a form field of type "markup")
 * $form[x]['score'] - the users score on the current question.(FAPI array usually of type "markup" or "textfield")
 * $form[x]['max_score'] - the max score for the current question.(FAPI array of type "value")
 * $form[x]['response'] - the users response, usually a FAPI array of type markup.
 * $form[x]['#is_correct'] - If the users response is correct(boolean)
 * $form[x]['#is_evaluated'] - If the users response has been evaluated(boolean)
 */
// $td_classes = array('quiz-report-odd-td', 'quiz-report-even-td');
// $td_class_i = 0;
$p = drupal_get_path('module', 'quiz') .'/theme/';
$q_image = $p. 'question_bg.png';
?>
<h2><?php print t('Question Results');?></h2>
<div class="quiz-report">
<?php
foreach ($form as $key => $sub_form):
  if (!is_numeric($key) || isset($sub_form['#no_report'])) continue;
  unset($form[$key]);
  $c_class = ($sub_form['#is_evaluated']) ? ($sub_form['#is_correct']) ? 'q-correct' : 'q-wrong' : 'q-waiting';
  $skipped = $sub_form['#is_skipped'] ? '<span class="quiz-report-skipped">'. t('(skipped)') .'</span>' : ''?>

    <div class="dt">
      <div class="quiz-report-score-container <?php print $c_class?>">
        <span>
          <?php print t('Score')?>
        <?php print drupal_render($sub_form['score'])?>
        <?php print t('of') .' '. $sub_form['max_score']['#value']?>
        <?php print '<br><em>'. $skipped .'</em>'?>
      </span>
    </div>
      <p class="quiz-report-question"><strong><?php print t('Question')?>: </strong></p>
      <?php print drupal_render($sub_form['question']);?>
    </div>
  <div class="dd">
    <p><strong><?php print t('Response')?>: </strong></p>
    <?php print drupal_render($sub_form['response']); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="dd">
    <?php print drupal_render($sub_form['answer_feedback']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<div class="quiz-score-submit"><?php print drupal_render_children($form);?></div>
```

Now I want to change this codes and I need a function to return the nid(number of id) of quiz that the user is seeing.
please help me.

Comment: have u check this thread https://drupal.org/node/1989052 it may help u

Comment: Do you only want the quiz' NID, then `arg(1)` is all you need. But if you need the NID of the current question, then [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/174716/15055) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to get the nid of the *node currently being viewed*:

```
$path = current_path();
list($entity_type, $entity_id) = explode('/', $path);
```

After this, you will have the entity id (the nid in the case of nodes) in the variable $entity_id.

Comment: Or [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)? (anything that avoids using the awful `list()` function goes in the win column for me). Bear in mind this will only work for nodes, and entities who specifically define their URI as `entity_type/%`, and entities whose URI callback function hasn't been overwritten to move the identifier within the path. It also won't work for entities like taxonomy terms, whose path is `taxonomy/term/%`. `menu_get_object()` is considered the best solution for nodes specifically.

Comment: You are right, but since the OP specifically asked for an nid, IMO generic application isn't a high priority concern  here.  And since it will go into a template file, there is effectively 0 risk of a misfire.  As for list(), I find it simple and concise.

Comment: Sure, there are quite a few ways to skin that particular cat - it's just `menu_get_object()` is the recommended one.